# Write into CSV from a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write into a CSV some Hash elements.
`@boo_hoo` is my hash
for each of its keys, if they have a single value, I don't want them in the CSV. There must be something wrong with my syntax. Could someone please explain a bit how to access the key+values of a hash in this case?
Thanks!

```
CSV.open("final_data.csv", "wb") {|csv| 
    @boo_hoo.to_a.each.count {|k, v|
        count.v > 1 csv << |k, v|
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message? Also, what is the expected output? What exactly do you want? Write into CSV from hash or access key,values of a hash in ruby?

Comment: I think count.v should be v.count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you next write a post, you can use the code formatting tools to make it a bit easier to read.

I can see a few errors here.

1. As per Mark's comment, `count.v` should be `v.count`.
2. You've combined two statements on one line with no separator, so I'd guess your error message is like `unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input`. You want to chain them together so that if your condition is met, then the args are added to the csv.
3. Vertical pipes `|k, v|` are used to denote block arguments in ruby, but you're repeating them when you probably want an array.
4. I don't really see what `.to_a.each.count` is doing for you, except possibly causing more syntax errors.

To write this in one line:

```
CSV.open("final_data.csv", "wb") {|csv| @boo_hoo.each {|k, v| csv << [k, v] if v.count > 1 } }
```

That might be a bit long, so I'd be tempted to break out the block into a multiline block:

```
CSV.open("final_data.csv", "wb") do |csv| 
  @boo_hoo.each {|k, v| csv << [k, v] if v.count > 1 } 
end
```

EDIT: You've edited your post as I wrote this. In ruby, it's an idiom to use single braces `{}` for a block consisting of a single line of code, but `do ... end` for a block that stretches over multiple lines.

Also, in response to Mudasobwa's comment, you probably want to add a splat operator  `[k,*v]`. My code is valid ruby, but the output probably isn't what you want. Let's say `@boo_hoo = {:a=>[1, 2, 3], :b=>[1], :c=>[1, 2]}`. The code above produces the output

```
a,"[1, 2, 3]"
c,"[1, 2]"
```

If you change the block to

```
@boo_hoo.each {|k, v| csv << [k, *v] if v.count > 1 }
```

you get the output

```
a,1,2,3
c,1,2
```

which is almost certainly what you actually want in a CSV.

Comment: I believe `csv << [k, v] if v.count > 1` will confuse `CSV` library. `csv << [k, *v] if v.count > 1` looks more appropriate here (note the splat.)

Comment: I thought about this, but didn't have a chance to look into it too deeply earlier. I'll add something about this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rwold for explaining in so much detail, it worked :)

Comment: No problem. If you mark the question as being answered, it will save other people reading through it trying to help with unanswered questions.